# How to get a command to run automatically in RStudio Terminal

Tags: terminal, rstudio

I'm on Windows 10.
I want to send a command to a Terminal in RStudio using the rstudioapi. For example:

```
termId <- rstudioapi::terminalCreate()
rstudioapi::terminalSend(termId, 'dir\n')
```

My issue is that although the command is sent to the terminal, it does not run automatically. The cursor stays at the end of the line and I need to manually go to the terminal and press `Enter`.

I have seen many other terminal questions which have the `\n` at the end of the commands, so I'm certain it should work.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
> sessionInfo()
```

```
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Argentina.utf8  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Argentina.utf8    LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Argentina.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=Spanish_Argentina.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rstudioapi_0.13 RPostgres_1.4.4 DBI_1.1.3      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] bit_4.0.4       compiler_4.2.1  ellipsis_0.3.2  cli_3.3.0       hms_1.1.1       tools_4.2.1     Rcpp_1.0.8.3   
 [8] bit64_4.0.5     vctrs_0.4.1     blob_1.2.3      lifecycle_1.0.1 pkgconfig_2.0.3 rlang_1.0.3
```

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody has the same issue:
I simply replaced the `\n` with `\r` and it worked.  Don't really understand it as in another laptop it works fine with `\n`.